# Default Zero Value Setting in Dynamic Form Dropdown Control in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6, dynamic-forms

I am working on dynamic form building in Angular 6, currently I have three controls drop-down, multi-drop-down and input field. These fields used as filters to load reports and according to requirements report can be open with some default selected values.
Many of the filters set if I set the selectedValue in drop-down control but some of drop-down default selected value is zero which is not getting set by default

Here is how I set default values in Dynamic Control Base

```
  getReportControls(prompts) {
    const promptControls: DynamicControlBase<any>[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < prompts.length; i++) {
      const defaultValue = this.getDefaultSelectedValue(prompts[i]);
      if (prompts[i].PromptControlType === 'dropdown' || prompts[i].PromptControlType === 'dropdown-multiple') {
        promptControls.push(new DropdownDynamic({
          key: prompts[i].PromptKey,
          label: prompts[i].PromptLabel,
          options: prompts[i].PromptData,
          order: prompts[i].PromptOrder,
          controlType: prompts[i].PromptControlType,
          controlID: prompts[i].ComponentPromptID,
          required: prompts[i].IsPromptRequired,
          dataSource: prompts[i].PromptDataSource,
          parameterName: prompts[i].PromptParameterName,
          visible: true,
          mstrKey: prompts[i].PromptMSTRKey,
          onLoadPopulate: prompts[i].IsLoadPopulated,
          spParameterCount: prompts[i].PromptSPParameterCount,
          value: defaultValue,
          selectedValue: defaultValue
        }));
      }
    }

    return promptControls;
  }
```

Above method create dynamicFormControls object which further used by this, **selectedValue** property work for every default value other than zero.
**prompts** come from db based on which form controls are made and in case of zero default value is integer and drop-down key value pair is also integer

Here is how dynamic Form Builder

```
<div>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div mat-list-item *ngFor="let dynamicFormControl of dynamicFormControls" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
        <dynamic-form-control [dynamicFormControl]="dynamicFormControl" [form]="form"></dynamic-form-control>
      </div>

      <div mat-list-item class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
        <button mat-stroked-button class="whiteBtn" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">View Report</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this how each control get Render

```
<div [formGroup]="form">

  <div [ngSwitch]="dynamicFormControl.controlType">
    <mat-form-field class="mb10" *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'">
      <mat-label [attr.for]="dynamicFormControl.key">{{ dynamicFormControl.label }}</mat-label>
      <input [formControlName]="dynamicFormControl.key" [id]="dynamicFormControl.key" [type]="dynamicFormControl.type" [required]="dynamicFormControl.required" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">
      <mat-label [attr.for]="dynamicFormControl.key">{{ dynamicFormControl.label }}</mat-label>
      <mat-select [id]="dynamicFormControl.key" [formControlName]="dynamicFormControl.key" [required]="dynamicFormControl.required" (selectionChange)="selectedValueChanged($event, dynamicFormControl)">
        <mat-option *ngIf="!dynamicFormControl.required" selected>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of dynamicFormControl.options" [value]="opt.Prompt_Key">
          {{opt.Prompt_Name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="!isValid">{{ dynamicFormControl.label }} is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown-multiple'">
      <mat-label [attr.for]="dynamicFormControl.key">{{ dynamicFormControl.label }}</mat-label>
      <mat-select multiple [id]="dynamicFormControl.key" [formControlName]="dynamicFormControl.key" [required]="dynamicFormControl.required" (selectionChange)="selectedValueChanged($event, dynamicFormControl)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of dynamicFormControl.options" [value]="opt.Prompt_Key">
          {{opt.Prompt_Name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="!isValid">{{ dynamicFormControl.label }} is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there an element in dynamicFormControl.options where opt.Prompt_Key is zero when default selected value is zero?

Comment: yes there is element in dynamicFormControl.options where opt.Prompt_Key is zero which will be set as default

Comment: then my best guess is that there may be a type issue. such that opt.Prompt_Key has a string value where formControl has a number or vice versa. in order to evaluate further, i ll need a working demo on stackblitz.

Comment: No both have integer value